# Accessing non-static class variable from static methods in C++

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, static-variables

The issue with static functions is that it accepts static class variables and functions only. A workaround is possible.

```
Class A{
int x;
static void function()
{
    A *a= new A();
    a->x; //this way we can access the non-static functions
    free(a);
    }
}
```

But lets assume this case in queues.

```
Class A{
queue x;
static void function1()
{
    A *a= new A();
    a->x.push(some argument); //this way we can access the non-static functions
    free(a);
}

static void function2()
{
    A *a= new A();
    a->x.pop(); //this way we can access the non-static functions
    free(a);
}
```

}

each function1 and function2 will create a queue of its own instance i.e. a, meaning queue x is different for both the functions.

How can we make the same queue accessible by both the functions with out making it static, is there a work around, please notice that function1() and function2() are running in threads parallely. Hence function1() is sort of independent of function2() and vice versa.

Comment: Why `without making it static` requirement? Or alternatively, why do `functdion1` and `function2` need to be static?

Comment: I dont know the static requirement, but I have been told to. The function1 and function2 need to be static because they are passed in pthread_create functions in a separate in .h and .cpp implementation.

Comment: Apart from the actual question being asked and answered, you **really** shouldn't mix `a = new A()` with `free(a)`. If you `new` something, `delete` it. If you `malloc()` something, `free()` it.

Comment: `pthread_create` expects a pointer to a function taking `void*`, and also takes a `void*` parameter that it passes along to said function. A typical approach is to pass `this` there: your `function1` and `function2` would then have an `A*` pointer to work with. As written, without a parameter, they are not suitable for `pthread_create` anyway.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you mean something like function1(A *a) but when I do this the pthread_create() argument expects function1(void*), and gives a conversion error, any thoughts?

Comment: No, I mean something like `void function1(void* arg) {A* p = static_cast<A*>(arg); ...}` And no, `pthread_create` does not expect `function1(void)` Do read the fine manual.

Comment: see singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to review your design first why you need this.

By the way, you can pass queue as an argument to the functions. This will allow `function1` and `function2` to access same queue. However, as they are in parallel, you may need locking mechanism.
But queue must be created before calling `function1`/`function2` and they should not free it.

```
static void function1(A *a)
{
    a->x.push(some argument); //this way we can access the non-static functions
}

static void function2(A *a)
{
    a->x.pop(); //this way we can access the non-static functions
}
```

I also think that this way is not a workaround but a clean solution.

Comment: actually the program will work in a serial fashion rather than a parallel fashion but I guess this seems the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: when I do this the pthread_create() argument expects function1(void* ), and gives a conversion error, any thoughts?

Comment: You can typecast `void *` to `A*`.